# How to install git repo using apt-get?

Tags: apt, git

I want to install my new git hub application to system using command like

```
apt-get install <application_name>
```

rather than cloning git repo and compiling and moving the file to /bin/folder.

Comment: Welcome to the the Unix and Linux stack exchange! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get information on how to best post to the site. Take the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) if you are not familiar with how this site works. To get to your question, have you packaged your application as a deb file and published it to a repository in your `sources.list`? Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/516945/edit) your post to include these details. Thank you!

Comment: `apt-get` requires a Debian package manager package, and won't work with a git repository. So the answer is "you can't do that". I also recommend **not** moving files to `/bin`, because you'll quickly loose track what you moved there. Instead, install self-compiled applications into `/usr/local` using e.g. `stow` (so you install into one subdirectory tree per "package", and then create symlinks from `/usr/local/bin` etc.).

Comment: You need to make a Debian `.deb` package out of it, and then either set up a PPA or get it into the Debian archives.  Check out https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345/what-is-the-simplest-debian-packaging-guide

Comment: In short, this is not the usual way to install things. Follow the install guide on the specific github project (there usually is one) instead of using `apt` and friends.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so

```
apt install -y python3 python3-pip
apt install -y git
pip3 install git+https://github.com/path/to.git
```